# How can I extract all links from the page excluding one using Perl's WWW::Mechanize?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I'm trying to use [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW::Mechanize) to extract some links from the HTML page using `find_all_links()` method. It supports matching on these criterias:

- text
- text_regex
- url
- url_regex
- url_abs
- url_abs_regex
  ...

How can I extract all links **except** one that has text "xyz"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `'text_regex'` criteria:

```
$mech->find_all_links(text_regex => qr/^(?!xyz$).*$/);
```

See [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for more on negative look-ahead assertion.

Answer (score 1):

Why not get all links then use 'grep' to skip those you don't need?

Comment: Why not answer a question with a question?

Comment: This approach is ok. In my script, params to find_all_links() are created dynamically. I find it easier to just use these params, w/o any special cases